# Unwanted dashed black border when rotating image in php

Tags: php

I am getting unwanted dashed black border when I rotate an image. I have tried to remove that but I am not finding any success. I am using the following function for image rotation. I try to preserve transparency. I have provided a image as well.

```
Here is an Image URL: http://s23.postimg.org/hep2pkol7/border.png 


function imageRotation ($source, $rotang)
{
    imagealphablending($source, false);
    imagesavealpha($source, true);
    $rotation = imagerotate($source, $rotang, imageColorAllocateAlpha($source, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($rotation, false);
    imagesavealpha($rotation, true);

    return $rotation;
}
```

I call the function something like that:

```
$rotatedImage = imageRotation($image, 10);
```

Here is the full code

```
<?php
    // Some settings
    $text = "Previously blogging"; 
    $fontFace = 'Days.ttf';
    $fontSize = 90;
    $angle = 0;


    $bbox = calculateTextBox($text, $fontFace, $fontSize, $angle);
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($bbox['width'], $bbox['height']);
    // Define some colors
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $yellow = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    //Fill the image with background color
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $yellow);
    // Draw text
    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, $angle, $bbox['left'], $bbox['top'], $black, $fontFace, $text);


    $image = imageRotation($image, 20);


    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('weight-loss.jpg');
        // Switch antialiasing on for one image
    imageantialias($im, true);
    $destWidth = imagesx($im);
    $destHeight = imagesy($im);
    $src_w = imagesx($image);
    $src_h = imagesy($image);

    $dst_x = ($destWidth - $src_w)/2;
    $dst_y = ($destHeight - $src_h)/2;

    imagecopy($im, $image, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h);

    header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im, null, 100);
    imagedestroy($im);
    imagedestroy($image);






    function calculateTextBox($text,$fontFile,$fontSize,$fontAngle)
    {
        $rect = imagettfbbox($fontSize,$fontAngle,$fontFile,$text);

        $minX = min(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
        $maxX = max(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
        $minY = min(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));
        $maxY = max(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));

        return array(
            "left"   => abs($minX),
            "top"    => abs($minY),
            "width"  => $maxX - $minX,
            "height" => $maxY - $minY,
            "box"    => $rect
            );
    }




    function imageRotation ($source, $rotang)
    {
        imagealphablending($source, false);
        imagesavealpha($source, true);
        $rotation = imagerotate($source, $rotang, imageColorAllocateAlpha($source, 0, 0, 0, 127), 0);
        imagealphablending($rotation, false);
        imagesavealpha($rotation, true);

        return $rotation;
    }





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is neither a dashed border, nor a border at all actually. This happens because your images are low-resolution, what cause the the rotated borders to "break", because actual pixels don't rotate.

That's what I'm trying to explain:

1. A line, parallel to the "pixel construction"; one px is three dashes long:

   ```
   -------------------------------------
   ```

   It would look smooth.
2. Rotated line:

   ```
   ---
      ---
         ---
            ---
               ---
                  ---
                     ---
   ```

   As you see, due to low resolution, it steps, not smoothly goes down.

If you use the higher resolution, the issue would go away. The visual effect of the "black" border appears because your white image contrasts with the other part of image.

Comment: Hi, I am creating the text image on the fly, but the destination image is 1280x720 in resolution. How to improve image's quality dynamically? Any clues.

Comment: @user can't you just specify a greater width and height for the rotated image?

Comment: Isn't this effect called Aliasing ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php

Comment: Still, I am unable to do it; anyway, I am posting the full code.